"Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column ..."
I have the following dataframe:
Price                       Adj Close       Close        High         Low        Open    Volume      ema_10      ema_20      ema_40      ema_50       sma_5      sma_10      n_high       n_low
Ticker                           AAPL        AAPL        AAPL        AAPL        AAPL      AAPL
Date
2023-11-13 00:00:00+00:00  183.899063  184.800003  186.029999  184.210007  185.820007  43627500  184.800003  184.800003  184.800003  184.800003         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2023-11-14 00:00:00+00:00  186.526199  187.440002  188.110001  186.300003  187.699997  60108400  185.280003  185.051432  184.928784  184.903532         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2023-11-15 00:00:00+00:00  187.093430  188.009995  189.500000  187.779999  187.850006  53790500  185.776365  185.333199  185.079086  185.025354         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2023-11-16 00:00:00+00:00  188.785126  189.710007  190.960007  188.649994  189.570007  54412900  186.491573  185.750038  185.304985  185.209066         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2023-11-17 00:00:00+00:00  188.765244  189.690002  190.380005  188.570007  190.250000  50922700  187.073105  186.125273  185.518888  185.384789  187.930002         NaN         NaN         NaN
...                               ...         ...         ...         ...         ...       ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
2024-11-04 00:00:00+00:00  221.766006  222.009995  222.789993  219.710007  220.990005  44944500  228.087639  228.953961  227.718509  226.698000  226.920001  229.660001  236.850006  219.710007
2024-11-05 00:00:00+00:00  223.204422  223.449997  223.949997  221.139999  221.800003  28111300  227.244431  228.429774  227.510289  226.570628  224.876001  228.419000  236.850006  219.710007
2024-11-06 00:00:00+00:00  222.475235  222.720001  226.070007  221.190002  222.610001  54561100  226.421808  227.885986  227.276616  226.419623  223.400000  227.615001  236.850006  219.710007
2024-11-06 00:00:00+00:00  222.475235  222.720001  226.070007  221.190002  222.610001  54561100  226.421808  227.885986  227.276616  226.419623  223.400000  227.615001  236.850006  219.710007
2024-11-06 00:00:00+00:00  222.475235  222.720001  226.070007  221.190002  222.610001  54561100  226.421808  227.885986  227.276616  226.419623  223.400000  227.615001  236.850006  219.710007
2024-11-06 00:00:00+00:00  222.475235  222.720001  226.070007  221.190002  222.610001  54561100  226.421808  227.885986  227.276616  226.419623  223.400000  227.615001  236.850006  219.710007
2024-11-07 00:00:00+00:00  227.229996  227.479996  227.880005  224.570007  224.630005  42137700  226.614206  227.847321  227.286537  226.461206  223.713998  227.306000  236.850006  219.710007

And I'm trying to create a new column using the following statement:
dfDaily['%K'] = (dfDaily['Close'] - dfDaily['n_low']) * 100 / (dfDaily['n_high'] - dfDaily['n_low'])

But I get the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr2024\ORDER\VanaromHuot\stockMA6.py", line 107, in <module>
    dfDaily['%K'] = (dfDaily['Close'] - dfDaily['n_low']) * 100 / (dfDaily['n_high'] - dfDaily['n_low'])
    ~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\yfinance\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4301, in __setitem__
    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\yfinance\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4459, in _set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column %K


The error message explains the error. Look at the computation on the right - it is a dataframe, not a series

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? Like to start, do you understand what the error is saying? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Also, please make a good reproducible pandas example using smaller input data. It looks like you could remove the columns that aren't being used as well as only keep the first few rows.

On second thought, you could keep one extra column, Open, for context

Oops, I just realized the "first few rows" of n_high and n_low are all NaN, so maybe use the last few rows instead.

If there is only one ticker, here AAPL:
Because MultiIndex in columns, it is possible to remove the second level of MultiIndex (Ticker level) by DataFrame.droplevel:
dfDaily = dfDaily.droplevel(axis=1, level=1)
dfDaily['%K'] = ((dfDaily['Close'] - dfDaily['n_low']) * 100 / 
                 (dfDaily['n_high'] - dfDaily['n_low']))

If output is one column DataFrame, it is possible to select it:
dfDaily['%K'] = ((dfDaily['Close'] - dfDaily['n_low']) * 100 / 
                 (dfDaily['n_high'] - dfDaily['n_low'])['AAPL'])


If there are multiple tickers:
df = ((dfDaily['Close'] - dfDaily['n_low']) * 100 / 
      (dfDaily['n_high'] - dfDaily['n_low']).add_prefix('%K_'))

out = pd.concat([dfDaily, df], axis=1)

